# VueJS Component Input Sync

Tags: vue.js, two-way, vue-component

I want to create components which have input which two-way bind to the local scope of the component.

Without a component, I would create a new `Vue` instance and then set my `data` to what I need. Then using `v-model`, bind an input to that data and it can be manipulated from the input.

However, converting the same code to a component, I cannot for the life of me get any input in a component to bind to its data. I have tried props, `:data.sync`, `data` attributes but no matter what I have tried, the input within a component does nothing.

I have created a JSFiddle to illustrate this:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/f0pdmLhy/2/

What I would like to happen is the input in the component to two way bind to the err variable, just like the non component version underneath.

How would I accomplish this?

I basically want to create components that I can instansiate with ajax data and then populate the inputs. The inputs could then update the data and I can use a save method to send the data to the server. Can this even be done using components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of things:

- The external resource you were using was somehow faulty. I've used
  `jsfiddle` default `Vue` instance and it works fine.
- When you declare a component, you should not define the data as an object, but as a function returning an object. Read here: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Component-Option-Caveats

A working example here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/by4csn1b/1/

Comment: If you edit the text in the 123 input, the text to the left of the input does not update. If you edit the text in the Hello input, the text to the left does update. I want the 123 next to the input of the component to be bound to the input value. thats whats not working, even in your example

Comment: Changing :value to v-model worked for me. I dont know why I didnt try that, the documentation made no mention of it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with components, the reactivity can be accomplished just like with an instance.

One catch with components, is that `data` must be a function that returns an object.

Also, to maintain the two way binding, use `v-model` in your input.

```
Vue.component('ii', {
    template: '<span>{{err}}</span><input type="text" v-model="err"><hr>',
  data: function () {
    return {
       err: 123
    }
  }
})
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/f0pdmLhy/25/